# Why is my code not passing to my div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a gameserver query for my website, and I want it to load the content, save it, and echo it later. However, it doesn't seem to be echoing. It selects the element by ID and is supposed to echo the content of the VAR.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<center><div id="cstrike-map"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Please wait ...</b><br /></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var map = "";
            var hostname = "";
            var game = "";
            var players = "";
        $.post( "serverstats-cstrike/cstrike.php", { func: "getStats" }, function( data ) {
            map = ( data.map );
            hostname = ( data.hostname );
            game = ( data.game );
            players = ( data.players );
        }, "json"); 
        function echoMap(){
            document.getElementByID("cstrike-map");
            document.write("<h5>Map: " + map + "</h5>");
        }
    </script>
```

PHP files:



**query.php**

```
/* SOURCE ENGINE QUERY FUNCTION, requires the server ip:port */
function source_query($ip)
{
$cut = explode(":", $ip);
$HL2_address = $cut[0];
$HL2_port = $cut[1];

$HL2_command = "\377\377\377\377TSource Engine Query\0";
$HL2_socket = fsockopen("udp://".$HL2_address, $HL2_port, $errno, $errstr,3);
fwrite($HL2_socket, $HL2_command); $JunkHead = fread($HL2_socket,4);
$CheckStatus = socket_get_status($HL2_socket);

if($CheckStatus["unread_bytes"] == 0)
{
    return 0;
}

$do = 1;
while($do)
{
    $str = fread($HL2_socket,1);
    $HL2_stats.= $str;
    $status = socket_get_status($HL2_socket);
    if($status["unread_bytes"] == 0)
    {
        $do = 0;
    }
}
fclose($HL2_socket);

$x = 0;
while ($x <= strlen($HL2_stats))
{
    $x++;
    $result.= substr($HL2_stats, $x, 1);    
}
$result = urlencode($result); // the output
return $result;
} 

/* FORMAT SOURCE ENGINE QUERY (assumes the query's results were urlencode()'ed!) */
function format_source_query($string)
{
$string = str_replace('%07','',$string);
$string = str_replace("%00","|||",$string);
$sinfo = urldecode($string);
$sinfo = explode('|||',$sinfo);
$info['hostname'] = $sinfo[0];
$info['map'] = $sinfo[1];
$info['game'] = $sinfo[2];
if ($info['game'] == 'garrysmod') { $info['game'] = "Garry's Mod"; }
elseif ($info['game'] == 'cstrike') { $info['game'] = "Counter-Strike: Source"; }
elseif ($info['game'] == 'dod') { $info['game'] = "Day of Defeat: Source"; }
elseif ($info['game'] == 'tf') { $info['game'] = "Team Fortress 2"; }
$info['gamemode'] = $sinfo[3];
return $info;
}
```

**cstrike.php**

```
include('query.php');
$ip = 'play1.darkvoidsclan.com:27015';
$query = source_query($ip); // $ip MUST contain IP:PORT
$q = format_source_query($query);

$host =  "<h5>Hostname: ".$q['hostname']."</h5>";
$map = "<h5>Map: ".$q['map']."</h5>";
$game = "<h5>Game: ".$q['game']."</h5>";
$players = "Unknown";

$stats = json_encode(array( 
"map" => $map, 
"game" => $game,
"hostname" => $host,
"players" => $players
 ));
```

Comment: to see the output of the current code, click [here](http://darkvoidsclan.com/home/servers.php)

Comment: Your AJAX callback function sets a bunch of variables, but it doesn't update anything in the DOM to display them.

Comment: I don't understand what your `echoMap` function is doing. You call `getElementById`, but don't assign it to anything. Then you call `document.write()`, which will replace your entire page if you call it after the page is finished loading.

Comment: @Barmar Could you lead me in the right direction for updating content in the DOM to display my variables? _maybe documentation?_

Comment: @Barmar the echoMap function was an attempt to try and show the contents of the AJAX callback. Also, could you elaborate on the `getElementByID` assignment and a better way to replace content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was I had to echo the content that I needed into the PHP file, then grab the HTML content and use it.

That seemed to be the most powerful and easiest way to do what I wanted to do in the OP.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.post("stats/query.cstrike.php", {}, 
                    function (data) {
                        $('#serverstats-wrapper-cstrike').html (data);
                        $('#serverstats-loading-cstrike').hide();
                        $('#serverstats-wrapper-cstrike').show ("slow");
                    });
            });
        </script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    include 'query.php';
    $query = new query;
    $address = "play1.darkvoidsclan.com";
    $port = 27015;
    if(fsockopen($address, $port, $num, $error, 5)) {          
        $server = $query->query_source($address . ":" . $port);
        echo '<strong><h4 style="color:green">Server is online.</h4></strong>';
        if ($server['vac'] = 1){
            $server['vac'] = '<img src="../../images/famfamfam/icons/tick.png">';
        } else {
            $server['vac'] = '<img src="../../images/famfamfam/icons/cross.png">';
        }
        echo '<b>Map: </b>'.$server['map'].'<br />';
        echo '<b>Players: </b>'.$server['players'].'/'.$server['playersmax'].' with '.$server['bots'].' bot(s)<br />';
        echo '<b>VAC Secure: </b>&nbsp;'.$server['vac'].'<br />';
        echo '<br />';
    } else {
        echo '<strong><h4 style="color:red">Server is offline.</h4></strong>';
        die();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that I can't understand from your code, and `echoMap()` is a bit messed up... but assuming that your php is ok it seems you are not calling the echomap function when the post request is completed.

**Add** `echoMap()` **right after** `players = ( data.players );`

If the div id you want to modify is 'cstrike-map' you could use jQuery:

**Change the JS** `echoMap` **to this**

```
function echoMap(){
    $("#cstrike-map").html("<h5>Map: " + map + "</h5>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the response in the `$.post` callback:

```
$.post( "serverstats-cstrike/cstrike.php", { func: "getStats" }, function( data ) {
    $("#map").html(data.map);
    $("#hostname").html(data.hostname);
    $("#game").html(data.game);
    $("#players").html(data.players);
}, "json");
```

You haven't shown your HTML, so I'm just making up IDs for the places where you want each of these things to show.

Comment: I'd like to integrate your answer and @Ax_6's answer, but in order to do that, I would need to take the POST callback and display it in this manner: `function echoMap(){ $("#cstrike-map").html("<h5>Map: " + map + "</h5>"); }`

Comment: You can call `echoMap()` from the callback function. Instead of setting global variables, you should pass them as parameters to the function.